# How to start an application using Entity Framework + Repository + Unit of Work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository, unit-of-work

I plan to write my first application using Entity Framework + Repository + Unit of Work.

I'm looking for a good example where can I apply these patterns. I'm still learning of this scenario. Can you provide me a website or tutorial where explain how to implement them?

I've seen several articles from MSDN which publish that you can use POCO, another uses T4 templates. I guess utilizing them is take advantage of the time.

I've got to say, I'm newbie of this topic, and sorry if the question is stupid.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are newbie start with pure EF instead of going to take everything together.

Comment: Understand each technology individually before trying to mix them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with first part of an extensive post series by Steven Sanderson from http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

Steve demonstrates MVCScaffolding to scaffold controllers and views when provided with model classes.
Very useful series. I used it in my first MVC3 project extensively.

He also demonstrate repository pattern.

Credit goes to Steven Sanderson for creating such a wonderful series of posts.